# Graphics driver for Macbook Pro Retina BootCamp and AMD M370x

Tags: bootcamp, windows

Has anyone had any luck finding a BootCamp driver to work for the new 2015 MacBook Pro Retina with AMD m370x?

I've installed Windows 8.1, but the AMD driver installation tool says that there is no suitable hardware available, even though it clearly shows up display properties.

Maybe there is a Beta driver somewhere?

Why would there be terrible performance out of the gate for this video card, when it should be an upgrade from previous gen?

Comment: Problem is: the AMD m370x is not found! In the Device Manager it does not appear, only the Intel Pro. I am really frustrated .... Does anybody have a solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

Have you run the AMD driver setup from your `WININSTALL` flash drive? That should do it for you.

To find the setup file, open Windows File Explorer, and then go to `D:\BootCamp\Drivers\AMD\AMDGraphics\Setup.exe`. Remember to replace `D` with the correct disk that `WININSTALL` is on.